# Inheriting module/class methods

Tags: ruby

I have this module with a method:

```
module MySqlConnection
  def database_connect(application)
    # Code in here
  end
end
```

I have a second module with a class that uses `database_connect`:

```
module ResetPopups
  class PopupsOff
    include MySqlConnection
    def self.reset_popup
      database_connect("#{APP}")
    end
  end
end
```

When I call:

```
ResetPopups::PopupsOff.reset_popup
```

I get an `undefined method database_connect`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module ResetPopups
  class PopupsOff
    extend MySqlConnection
    def self.reset_popup
      database_connect("#{APP}")
    end
  end
end
```

would work

What is hapening here, is that you `include MySqlConnection`, which makes method defined in it (`database_connect`) instance methods. But you use this module in the class scope, calling the `database_connect` on the class.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers (that upvote on Marek's post was not me :-)) I'll accept this as the answer, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 5):

`include` adds module methods as instance methods, while `extend` adds them as singleton methods. Since you want to use this in the context of class (singleton context), you need to use `extend`:

```
extend MySqlConnection
```

Comment: how come you have the upvote 7 seconds after posting the answer even though I was first :D

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's because my answer had an explanation from the beginning? ;) +1 from me for 'balance'. :)

Comment: Thank you for answering, much appreciated

Comment: @MarekLipka, hm, you must be right (but still i've updated the answer earlier then yours appeared) ;) Then +1 from me for (as usual) being so fast with the explanation from the beginning :)